# Sort list values to get a new order of its index, Python way

Tags: python, sorting

Sorry for the vague of my question's title.
My question is, I have a list `a = [6, 9, 8, 10, 7, 5, 2, 3, 1, 4]`
I need to get the new order `b = [4, 2, 3, 5, 1, 6, 10, 8, 7, 9]`, where the first element of `b` is `4` because the 4th element of `a` `10` is the largest number in a. Similarly, the 2nd element in `b` is `2` because the second large number in a is its second number `9`

So, hopefully you got my question: Sort the list `a` and get the new order `b`.

Currently, I get it done by using `list.sort` with some prepare.

```
tmp = zip(range(1,11), a)
tmp.sort(key=lambda x:(-x[1],x[0]))
b = [x[0] for x in tmp]
```

I wonder whether there are better python way to achieve my goal?
Thanks for any suggestions~

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would just use the `key` argument to sort `range(1, len(a) + 1)` by using `a`'s values.

```
sorted(range(1, len(a) + 1), key=lambda i: a[i-1], reverse=True)
```

Comment: Brilliant.  I wish I had thought of it.  +1

Comment: I agree with @mgilson - very, very nice... the `range` could be made to have an end of `len(a) + 1` to make it more generic, but wow... +1

Comment: Thanks. I've changed it to use `len(a) + 1`.

Comment: @JonClements -- The aspect of our answers is that they'll work for any iterable whereas this one only works for iterables which are indexible and have a well defined len.

Comment: @mgilson What non-indexible iterables do you think of ?

Comment: @gilson Because of the ``a[i-1]`` ? Then, for **a** being a generator, an instruction ``a = tuple(a)`` must be added before the sorting, right ?

Comment: This solution is the valuable one: simple and the fastest one (I tested). It will be accepted, even if it applies only to indexible collections, as pointed out by mgilson. Because your age makes it a remarkable answer.

Answer (score 2):

That's basically the idea, but you can do:

```
import operator
tmp = sorted(enumerate(a,1),key=itemgetter(1,0),reverse=True)
b = [x[0] for x in tmp]

#In python2.x, the following are equivalent to the list comprehension.
#b = zip(*tmp)[0]
#b = map(itemgetter(0),tmp)
```

I think that `enumerate` is a little cleaner than `zip` with `range` and `itemgetter` is a little cleaner than `lambda`.

Comment: I think that ``itemgetter(1)`` is sufficient. And that it's even possible tonot use ``itemgetter`` : ``b = [x[0] for x in sorted(enumerate(a,1),key=lambda x: -x[1])]``

Comment: It is sufficient.  I was just keeping with OP's code.  and `itemgetter` is never *needed*.  As I said, I think it's a little cleaner -- As is `reverse=True` compared to negating `x[1]`.  (`reverse=True` will also work with strings for example)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sorted` and `enumerate`:

```
print [el[0] for el in sorted(enumerate(a, start=1), key=lambda L: L[1], reverse=True)]
# [4, 2, 3, 5, 1, 6, 10, 8, 7, 9]
```

For completeness an alternative using `numpy` (should you happen to use it any time in the near future):

```
np.argsort(a)[::-1] + 1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a = [6, 9, 8, 10, 7, 5, 2, 3, 1, 4]
b = [6, 9, 8, 10, 7, 5, 2, 3, 1, 4] 

a.sort(reverse = True)
print(a)
print(b)
c = [b.index(y)+1 for y in a ]
print(c)
```

i have just got this stupid answers...